# Is this a misunderstanding of the functionality of strcpy()?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {
    int number_of_members;

    char family[number_of_members][20][number_of_members][20];
    char member_name[20];
    char birth_state[20];
    char family_last_name[20];

    printf("What is the last name of the family?\n");
    scanf("%s", &family_last_name);

    printf("How many members do you want to create?\n");
    scanf("%d", &number_of_members);

    int const FAMILY_SIZE = number_of_members;

    number_of_members = number_of_members -1;
    printf("Enter the family member name: \n");

    for(number_of_members;number_of_members>-1;number_of_members--)
    {

        scanf("%s", &member_name);
        strcpy(family[number_of_members], member_name);


        printf(" %d %s %s\n",number_of_members, member_name, family_last_name);

    }
    printf("%s, %s ", family[0], family[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:(from Ideone.com)

[Ideone.com with code](https://ideone.com/Q1lP78)

The input to this code is: Layne , 2 , tim , jim.

When run, it shows the correct index with the name in the array however, once out it will show the last entered name, jim, as family[1](https://ideone.com/Q1lP78) and family[0]. Am I not understanding how strcpy() works? or is it a logic error?Some assistance soon would be appreciated!

Comment: WTF is `char family[number_of_members][20][number_of_members][20];`?????????????

Comment: @iharob a char array with indexes set by the user

Comment: You're using `number_of_members` before initializing it. In fact, your ridiculous array statement suggests you don't quite understand arrays and pointers in C

Comment: @DrewMcGowen You are correct I dont. Im very new to C. This is me trying to figure it out as well as a function in the c library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very very wrong

```
int number_of_members;
char family[number_of_members][20][number_of_members][20];
```

1. Because you haven't initialized `number_of_members`.
2. Because it doesn't make sense whatsoever, it's not possible that you really need this kind of array.

And yes, if you enable compiler warnings it will hit you in your nose with a stick, because

```
strcpy(family[number_of_members], member_name);
```

shouldn't even compile and is undefined behavior since the type of `family[number_of_members]`, is an array of arrays of arrays of `char`.

`strcpy` can take an array of `char`'s because it will be automatically converted to a `char` poitner, and provided that the contents of the array comply with what a c string is, then `strcpy()` will work correctly, in your case the behavior is undefined because almost surely the `'\0'` will never be found in the destination pointer.

Comment: appreciate it, im still learning any advice or opinons are appreciated

Comment: im quite new to c as you can easily see. The array will hold  2 things in it. The users state as well as their name i just had a hiccup in the process. Can you explain why strcpy overrides both indexes though?Is it due to the for loop? I tested it outside the loop by manually assigning them values and it worked.

Comment: If you need an array to hold 2 strings of length 100 then just `char[100][2]`.

Comment: number_of_members is initialized from the user though? they assign they value.Once created the array will ahve the indexes. It cannot work that way in C ?

Comment: ahh so array[20][4] would have 4 users. But what if i wanted each users to hold an additional string which would be the state?

Comment: @TimLayne you now need a struct `struct User {char name[20]; char string[20];};`

Comment: thank you I was mis-understanding the array.Completely. The second half of the array looks idiotic the more you guys explain.

Comment: Issue was resolved and you helped me understand strcpy a bit more. Appreciate the criticism.

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
int num_of_members;
char family[number_of_members][20][number_of_members][20];
```

which is not C code, do this

```
#define MAX_MEMBERS 20
char family[MAX_MEMBERS][20];
```

which creates a rectangular array of arrays each of 20 bytes long

Comment: `int num_of_memebrs = 20; char family[num_of_memebrs][20];` would also work. And you mispelled `num_of_members` did you know that you can select the text with your mouse hit `Ctrl+C` and then `Ctrl+V` and you don't need to type it?

Comment: I cannot allow the user to create the length of the array? If so i will jus remove that number of member crap and replace it with a number

Comment: Don't worry your answer is Ok it was just a **comment**, I am sorry I tend to sound like I don't want to.

Comment: I was just trying to provide more interactivity for the user and lengths of the array. The array must be initialized with concrete values not variables it seems?

Comment: @TimLayne if you want to let to specify length, then you have to use array of pointers,and dynamically allocate memory using malloc() and free() which im not sure you will able to do it properly. so just stick with constant length using rectangular arrays.

Comment: That is what I ended up going back to, I just tried to do more than I knew atm. There really wasnt a point to using strcpy or the extra length of that array. I reduced it to family[20][20] and eliminated strcpy. Im just going to have the user enter the string and assign each string to each array. Thank you. I need to explore Cs library more as well as understanding how to apply them, CORRECTLY.

Comment: sometimes I ask questions that make me look like a straight dumbass, this  being one.